kubernetes job workload container getting deleted after completion
I am trying to deploy a sample job in kubernetes cluster environment. After the job execution is completed. The respective container in the corresponding job's pod is getting deleted after sometime.
Here is the error we see in the cluster logs.

Error - E0719 00:00:00.409361 3174 cpu_manager.go:394] "RemoveStaleState: removing container" podUID="xxx" containerName="pi"

kubernetes version - v1.24.x
sample job definition
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: pi
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: pi
        image: perl:5.34.0
        command: ["perl",  "-Mbignum=bpi", "-wle", "print bpi(2000)"]
      restartPolicy: Never
  backoffLimit: 4

Do we have any way to ensure that cpu_manager does not removed the container after the job completion as once the container is removed i am unable to fetch the logs to analyze further and this is the error i see.
unable to retrieve container logs for docker://8efc123ae26dacebb8624eec7af8852f9205f42e2e2fcad586fd13eb4xxxxx

As per kubernetes docs it mentions the container logs should be available after the execution completes by default.

Try .spec.ttlSecondsAfterFinished

@SimonLi Can you post your comment as an elaborated answer for greater visibility for the community?

@SimonLi, even after updating the job definition with the extended TTL value, the container is getting removed even though the job and deployment exists in the cluster. The container is getting removed after around 2 hours or so.., Seems this is the code behind that action - https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/kubelet/cm/cpumanager/cpu_manager.go (line 394)
